# Xcode 4 Source Control Problem

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode4

When I use Xcode 4 to open Xcode 3 projects that SCM is already configured, things work fine (although it crashes sometimes).

But when I use "Checkout" and "Add working copy" in the "Repositories" in the organizer, there are problem.
The files on the Project Navigator show "?" and "A" for its source control badge no matter I checkout or update for how many times.

It seems that the source control function is not connecting correctly to the svn server.
It shows nothing when I click "Commit" on the "Source control" menu under "File". And the "Commit Selected Files" is disabled when right click on the files.

Only after clicking on "refresh status" numerous times, I can see the badge showing the correct status and I can update/commit my files for only a few seconds - then everything repeat as mentioned above.....

Does anyone encountered the same problem? I am very disappointed by Apple.

p.s. I use a svn server and it works well on xcode 3.x, eclipse and even command-line console.

Comment: I don't have the same problem but I have found that Xcode for source control is a bit flaky. Often it hangs. I am reverting to Versions for my svn interface.

Comment: Have your fixed the problem? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Mustafa No, I am using Xcode 3 now....